# Sorting a Array based on another array

Tags: java, arrays, treemap, sortedmap

I have 2 arrays :

The first one consists of names of persons . The second one gives me a count of number of names that have appeared in a page. 
Ex: Names=["James","Loiui","Mario","Peter"] 
count=[1,4,2,5]

now I tried with this code give below :

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> m = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
        m.put( count.get(i),Names.get(i));
```

But this doesnt work given there are repeating values of count . I figured out that the problem is with TreeMap as it stores only unique elements . Now to overcome problem of mine, are there any other valid solutions .

Comment: Names are likely to be unique, so you should use a `SortedMap<String, Integer>`. However if your goal is to sort by count, use a `SortedMap<Integer, List<String>>`.

Comment: But I want the final result to have descending order based on count ,i.e the most repeated name to appear first

Comment: Then you can use a `SortedMap<Integer, List<String>>`, as I said.

Comment: Then i cannot have 2 count values to be same !

Comment: Why? If you have two count values that are the same, you'll have a mapping from this value to a List of 2 names.

Comment: NO .. Not exactly .. I am getting just one value .  Can you tell where am  going worng :  for(Entry<Integer, List<String>> i:m.entrySet())
  {
   System.out.println(i.getValue()+"\n"+i.getKey());
   System.out.println(i.getValue().size());
  }

Comment: I don't know how you fill your map so this is hard to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class `PersonFrequency`, containing a name and a count. Create a **single** array or list of PersonFrequency instances. Sort this array by count:

Java 8 example:

```
List<PersonFrequency> list = new ArrayList<>(names.length);
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    list.add(new PersonFrequency(names[i], counts[i]);
}

list.sort(Comparator.comparing(PersonFrequency::getCount).reversed());

List<String> sortedNames = list.stream()
                               .map(PersonFrequency::getName)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In Java 7, the sort would become

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<PersonFrequency>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(PersonFrequency p1, PersonFrequency p2) {
        return Integer.compare(p2.getCount(), p1.getCount());
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please elaborate  .

Comment: Elaborate what? Isn't the example code sufficiently understandable?

Comment: Is there any means by which I can employ PersonFrequency List into java 1.7 ?

Comment: Of course. You just need to use Collections.sort() and define a Comparator using an anonymous class rather than a lambda. there must be hundreds of questions asking how to sort a list of objects in Java. Google for them, or read my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted alphabetically

```
    String [] names = {"Aaa","Bbb"};
    int [] count = {1,2};

    SortedMap<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        m.put(names[i], count[i]);
    }
```

Sorted by number:

```
    String [] names = {"Aaa","Bbb"};
    int [] count = {2,1};

    SortedMap<Integer, String> m = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        m.put(count[i],names[i]);
    }
```

For descending change your sorted map to this

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> m = new TreeMap<Integer, String>().descendingMap();
```

Comment: Agreed !  But i want the resultant result to be sorted based on the number of count values . and not alphabetically !

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous comments you can have a sorted map with Integer and ArrayList parameters as below,

```
SortedMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map=new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>().descendingMap();
```

Since you want the results to be in descending order I added descendingMap().

We use ArrayList because you may have duplicates in count array. More than one name can have the same count value. So one count will have a list of names.

And the complete code is below,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;



public class NameCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = {"James","Loiui","Mario","Peter"};
        int[] count = {1, 4, 2, 1};

        SortedMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map=new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>().descendingMap();
        ArrayList<String> nameList=null;

        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            if(map.get(count[i])==null)
            {
                nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
                nameList.add(names[i]);
                map.put(count[i], nameList);
            }
            else
            {
                map.get(count[i]).add(names[i]);
            }
        }

        for(int countVal : map.keySet())
        {
            ArrayList<String> namesListVal=map.get(countVal);

            System.out.print("\nCount  "+countVal+ ":  NAMES  : ");
            for(String name : namesListVal)
            {
                System.out.print(name+"  ");
            }

        }
    }

}
```